# Connecting system with any http site's database through my desktop application

Tags: java, mysql, database, javafx

Suppose, I have a website for a school to collect students information and data.And my site has a MySQL databse.So how can I or my desktop application get those data from my site's database?Basically, when I  use MySQL for my desktop application I write some line of codes to connect with my local MySQL database which is given below.

```
public settingdatabase(){
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rgacd","root", "");
        stat = con.createStatement();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Error: "+ex);

    }
}
```

But when I try to connect with any HTTP site's database throough my desktop application what should I do.
Thanks In Advance. :D

Comment: What do you mean by "any HTTP site's database"?

Comment: suppose my site name is apece.000webhostapp.com, and I want to connect to this site's database by the desktop application.

Comment: You need to know the ip address (or hostname) of the database, not the web server.

Answer (score 1):

Typically there are firewalls involved.  Many networks running web servers will only accept incoming http/https connections (ports 80 and 443).  Other ports (such as 3306 to connect to a mysql database) are closed to the outside world.  The web server for the site often connects to an application server (e.g. Tomcat) that has network privileges to access the internal database.

So the simple answer is usually you can't directly connect to the database backing any arbitrary website because you don't have access to it.

Here is a somewhat typical architecture courtesy of Tivoli and an IBM slide deck:

[image: architecture]

By design, in most cases, direct access to the RDBMS is simply inaccessible to the users outside the firewall.

Now, in the unusual case that the firewall allowed an open port to connect to the database from any external machine, then you could connect to the machine via a jdbc network connection (the same as you are doing by accessing the database over localhost:3306).  To establish such a connection you would need to use the publicly available address of the database machine (which may or may not be the same as the address used for the http connection, depending upon the network configuration of the system).